# Web Application button not updating in UI table

Tags: c#, html, web-applications

I have a dynamically created table that is created when a database name is selected from a dropdownlist. The table is for looking at the last logins for each user. In the table i have three columns that are, username, last login date and password. In each database the password is encrypted so I display it as a button that will decrypt on button push. When i push the button to decrypt, it work fine. But when i try to select a different database all values should load again, and they do except the password button. The decrypted password stays even though all other values are being refreshed. How can i get that dynamically created button to refresh as well?

Here is the section of code that creates the button:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += Password_Click;
button.CssClass = "BtnAsLink";
button.Text = dt.Rows[j][k].ToString();

TableCell btnCell = new TableCell();

btnCell.Controls.Add(button);

tr.Cells.Add(btnCell);
```

I tried adding autopostback to the button with no success. And I tried adding code to search for the button before adding a new one, but none are ever found. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after a few days...

I changed my code for the button from calling a c# method to on client click, javascript function. In the meantime, preventing a postback.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.ID = j.ToString() + k.ToString();
button.OnClientClick += "return DecryptPassword(\"" + button.ID + "\", \"" + dt.Rows[j][0].ToString() + "\")";
button.CssClass = "BtnAsLink";
button.Text = dt.Rows[j][k].ToString();
button.Attributes.Add("AutoPostback", "false");
```

In doing this, i loaded all necessary info into a hidden field when the page loads and extract the decrypted password from that string on button click.